# angular2 routing with express

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, angular

I am using ng2 alpha 42 version

My code is below:

The problem is I expected only ONE data in my output so I don't need to use (ng-for) in my jade.code, but the unexpected result we can see, how can I change this, please help!

express (it works when I check the API in PostMan)

```
router.get('/project/:id', function(req,res){
sql = "SELECT * FROM Projects WHERE id=" + "'" + req.params.id + "'"; 
db.query(sql,function(err,project){
    if(err){
        res.send(err);
    }else{
        res.json(project)
        console.log(project) 

    }
  })
})
```

ng2 code (not work)

```
export class Project{
id: string;
project: string;
constructor(public routeParams : RouteParams, 
            http:Http){
    //this.projects = [];
    this.id = routeParams.get('id')

    http.get('/api/projects/project/' + this.id)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(
            project => this.project = project


        )

}
}
```

jade code (template engine)

```
li(*ng-for="#a of project")
  h1 {{ a.title}}
  h1 {{ a.author}}

h1 {{project}}
```

The result:

```
first topic
author1
[object Object]
```

I expected the code in jade is:

```
h1 {{ project.title}}
h2 {{ project.author}}
```

but if I put this, there is an error in my console:

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined in [null]
```

fix this

In express, this recalls only one data

```
res.json(project[0])
```

In ng2, I forget to declare the project type

```
this.project = {};
```

This works. If you can give me any suggestions I would be thankful.